# Load Testing for Web Application

Tags: performance, testing, automated-tests, stress-testing

Expected Average User online will be  50000 – 100000 users and all user should register and submit the application which contains around maximum of 3MB data transfer per user  at a time.
Looking for cloud server.
How much bandwidth we need to run the web application?

Comment: Can you elaborate on which bandwidth you're talking about? Between your performance test server and the Server Under Test? If the latter, can you please elaborate on the 50,000 to 100,000 users? Is this a metric per hour, per month or otherwise. The 3 MB, is this continuous streaming per user, for all users or a total for each user session? If per session can you specify where the peak of this bandwidth usage is, at the start, middle or the end?

Comment: I need Bandwidth Calculation

Comment: I need Bandwidth Calculation. Am talking about Application Bandwidth. I planned to host my web application in cloud server. My Web application is like a flash sale site. possibly looking around 50000 to 100000 user will be online at a time. 3MB is maximum size[Page size and upload file size], 2-3 MB will be average size per users. total of each user session is 5-8MB. At start time the bandwidth is high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metrics that you've given are not complete to provide an accurate picture. The metrics only provide peak load, and not the distribution curve of the load across day/week. For now I'm assuming all days are equal and the peak lasts 8 hours, then scales down to 50% for another 8 hours and then 25% for the remaining 8 hours of the day.

In addition only the download data transfer is given and the upload is not provided. Assuming that all of the 3 Mb is download, and an additional 1 Mb of upload is expected.

Lastly there was nothing mentioned about the duration of the session of each concurrent user. This may be 10 minutes, 30 minutes or an hour. In the below tables all three scenario's are shown.

With these additional dimensions a rough load model can be calculated for each of the two user scenarios: 50K and 100K. Below I've kept to one scenario for the bandwidth capacity, as it's only a x2 multiplication.

The most extreme result for concurrent 50k users is 3 Mb of data is used in a single sessions of an average 10 minutes. This would require a line capacity of that is at least 500 Mb/s upload and 167 Mb/s download. This would result in a **daily** data transfer of 12 Tb Upload and 4 Tb down.

In case your sessions are much longer, say instead of 10 min it is an hour, then all these numbers can be divided by 6. I.e. resulting in a lower 2Tb Daily Upload and 0.7 Daily Download.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need using system high availability for application. I think you need 2 TB for 100k user submit form